# Why are high dimensional Bayes classification problems subject to numerical underflow?

Tags: machine-learning

I am reviewing slides for a big data class. They say that high-dimensional Naïve Bayes are prone to numerical underflow and unobserved events -- so you should take the log of the probabilities in calculating naive Bayes. What are these slides talking about?  I think of numeric underflow as losing precision because of variable type (ex. a big converted to an int). But that does not seem to be the meaning of the term in these slides. What do they mean by numeric underflow and unobserved events? How does taking the log of probabilities avoid these things in naive Bayes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computer only has finite precision.  So for example, on an ideal computer that computed things to infinite precision, this little Python program would never halt, it would just keep printing numbers closer and closer to 0.

```
x = 1.0
while x != 0:
  x = x * .5
  print x
```

But since the computer stores numbers in a fixed amount of bits, there are only so many numbers it can represent, and eventually it rounds the product to 0 and the loop exits.

The calculations in naive bayes happen like this when you have many features.  You multiply together lots and lots of probabilities that are less than 1, and eventually you can reach 0 due to machine precision issues.

Comment: "Flushing to zero" like this is not standard behaviour. Typically, without setting special options, you will get a NaN rather than a zero value. Perhaps python enables this for you.

Answer (score 1):

One common way of avoiding (or at least mitigating) the problem of arithmetic underflow is the use of log probabilities. Google something like "log probability underflow", and you should find lots of good hits.

This [link](https://facwiki.cs.byu.edu/nlp/index.php/Log_Domain_Computations) provides a good introduction. Here are other: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221080116/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2012/02/16/howprevent-overflow-underflow-logistic-regression) [Link](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/54259139/Using-log-transform-to-avoid-underflow-problem-in-computing).  There's a million of them out there - enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Btw, one reason that taking logs helps is that it converts products to sums.